# 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' while iterating through WebElements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Python and Selenium to scrape multiple links on a web page. I'm using `find_elements_by_xpath` and I'm able to locate a list of elements but I'm having trouble changing the list that is returned to the actual `href` links. I know `find_element_by_xpath` works, but that only works for one element.

Here is my code:

```
path_to_chromedriver = 'path to chromedriver location'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

browser.get("file:///path to html file")

all_trails = []

#finds all elements with the class 'text-truncate trail-name' then 
#retrieve the a element
#this seems to be just giving us the element location but not the 
#actual location

find_href = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="text truncate trail-name"]/a[1]')
all_trails.append(find_href)

print all_trails
```

This code is returning:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
(session="dd178d79c66b747696c5d3750ea8cb17", 
element="0.5700549730549636-1663")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
(session="dd178d79c66b747696c5d3750ea8cb17", 
element="0.5700549730549636-1664")>,
```

I expect the `all_trails` array to be a list of links like: `www.google.com, www.yahoo.com, www.bing.com`.

I've tried looping through the `all_trails` list and running the `get_attribute('href')` method on the list but I get the error:

[image: Picture of error]

Does anyone have any idea how to convert the selenium WebElement's to href links?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Notice that `find_elements_by_xpath` is plural; it returns a list. When you append what this produces to a list you will get a list of lists (not a list).

Comment: please paste your html here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let us see what's happening in your code :

Without any visibility to the concerned `HTML` it seems the following line returns two `WebElements` in to the `List` **`find_href`** which are inturn are appended to the **`all_trails`** `List` :

```
find_href = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="text truncate trail-name"]/a[1]')
```

Hence when we print the `List` **`all_trails`** both the `WebElements` are printed. Hence **No Error.**

As per the error snap shot you have provided, you are trying to invoke **`get_attribute("href")`** method over a `List` which is **Not Supported**. Hence you see the error :

```
'List' Object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

### Solution :

To get the **`href`** attribute, we have to iterate over the `List` as follows :

```
find_href = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//your_xpath')
for my_href in find_href:
    print(my_href.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="text-truncate trail-name">
<a href="http://google.com">Link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="text-truncate trail-name">
<a href="http://google.com">Link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="text-truncate trail-name">
<a href="http://google.com">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div class="text-truncate trail-name">
<a href="http://google.com">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

Your code should look like:

```
all_trails = []

all_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".text-truncate.trail-name>a")

for link in all_links:

    all_trails.append(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Where all_trails -- is a list of links (Link 1, Link 2 and so on).

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This actually returns none for some reason. DebanjanB's solution works above.

Thanks for the help, you definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
find_href = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="text truncate trail-name"]/a[1]')
for i in find_href:
      all_trails.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

`get_attribute` works on elements of that list, not list itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use it in Singular form as `find_element_by_css_selector` instead of using `find_elements_by_css_selector` as it returns many webElements in List. So you need to loop through each webElement to use Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

get_attribute works on elements of that list only, not list itself. For eg :-

```
def fetch_img_urls(search_query: str):
    driver.get('https://images.google.com/')
    search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "gLFyf.gsfi")
    search.send_keys(search_query)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    links=[]
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        urls = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a.VFACy.kGQAp.sMi44c.lNHeqe.WGvvNb')
        for url in urls:
            #print(url.get_attribute("href"))
            links.append(url.get_attribute("href"))
            print(links)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'error{e}')
        driver.quit()
```