# Trying to get text from span with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

EDIT: I figured out the culprit. That extra 's' certainly didn't do me any favors but the real issue was that I needed to switch to a new frame before searching for my element. Works like a charm now. Thanks for all the help!

---

I'm trying to pull the number of total results from various text searches in ServiceNow. I don't have access to the API so I'm having to brute force it a bit. Right now I have a python script that's using selenium to run the search. My problem is that for the life of me I can't scrape the results.

Here's the snippet of my code that isn't working:

```
elm_result = web_driver.find_elements_by_name("ts_count_8c58a5aa0a0a0b07008047e8ef0fe07d")
print("Total results: ", elm_result.text)
```

And here's the html and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fduPW.png) of the page it's pulling from:

```
<span name="ts_count_8c58a5aa0a0a0b07008047e8ef0fe07d" id="ts_count_8c58a5aa0a0a0b07008047e8ef0fe07d">
&nbsp;(162 matches)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <em>
      <span class="search_no_results">No matches for <a title="" class="noresultlink" href="ticket_list.do sysparm_query=123TEXTQUERY321%3DSAP%5Eactive%3Dtrue">Tickets</a>
         <span>
         </span>
      </span>
   </em>
</span>
```

When I run the script it seems to hang on this last little before eventually throwing out the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...", line 35, in <module> print("Total results: ", elm_result.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I've tried attacking it from a bunch of different angles but nothing seems to work. My goal is to get the "162 results" text into a variable that I can then pass onto a csv.

Comment: you should use `find_element_by_name`, rather than `find_elements_by_name` which return a List (List has no accribute 'text')

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['list' object has no attribute 'get\_attribute' while iterating through WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735375/list-object-has-no-attribute-get-attribute-while-iterating-through-webelemen)

Comment: Push your HTML when you have some search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `find_element_by_name` instead of `find_elements_by_name`. `find_elements_by_name` returns a WebElement, which has an attribute `text`, while `find_elements_by_name` return a list of WebElement.

Here is examples.

```
elm_result = web_driver.find_element_by_name("ts_count_8c58a5aa0a0a0b07008047e8ef0fe07d")
print("Total results: ", elm_result.text)
```

or you can specify an index of the list.

```
elm_result = web_driver.find_elements_by_name("ts_count_8c58a5aa0a0a0b07008047e8ef0fe07d")
print("Total results: ", elm_result[0].text)
```

**EDIT**

There is another problem which is about wait time for the login. You can add thread sleep or using Selenium wait for a specific element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
...
...
elm_result = WebDriverWait(web_driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'ts_count_8c58a5aa0a0a0b07008047e8ef0fe07d')))
print("Total results: ", elm_result.text)
```

Comment: When I drop the "s" it is unable to find the element, giving the error:  
     "Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"ts_count_8c58a5aa0a0a0b07008047e8ef0fe07d"}"      I get the same result when modified for find_by_id, find_by_css, and even find_by_xpath.