# Looping through rows of a table while clicking links in selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

**The sample page source looks like this**

```
<div class='div1'>
  <table class="foot-market">
    <tbody data-live="false">
      <td class='today-name'/>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-live="false">
      <td class='today-name'/>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-live="false">
      <td class='today-name'/>
    </tbody>
  </table

  <table class="foot-market">
    <tbody data-live="false">
      <td class='today-name'/>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-live="false">
      <td class='today-name'/>
    </tbody>
    <tbody data-live="false">
      <td class='today-name'/>
    </tbody>
  </table
</div>
```

**Explanation**
Hi,
So let's get to it. 
As shown above the code snippet I'm interacting with is housed in a `<div class='div1'>`.
The `<td class='today-name'>` is clickable and once clicked it renders a page(*the page of interest*)

so I would like to loop through getting each `<tbody data-live="false">` and click it.

From my research I haven't found anything similar but I have found interesting stuff but nothing to help. I appreciate all help given.

Thanks.

**my code**

```
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#some of the imports are for headless firefox so don't mind them
#for.testing.purposes.only
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'here://code.above.com/'
driver.get(url)

#looping rows in selenium
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='foot-market']")

for row in table.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@data-live='false']"):
    row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='today-name']").click()

    #try for one row first
    # driver.back()
    break
```

**Error**

The error returned is in line:

`for row in table.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@data-live='false']"):`

**Exception**:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

which makes sense and all, but how do I achieve this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['list' object has no attribute 'get\_attribute' while iterating through WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735375/list-object-has-no-attribute-get-attribute-while-iterating-through-webelemen)

Comment: Have a look at it. the td is clickable ad is housed in a tbody. So i am looping through the tbody's while clicking each td...the issue is how do i click this:: row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='today-name']").click()  since using driver instead of row it will not loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing says it all :

```
for row in table.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@data-live='false']"): AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

The following line is error prone :

```
for row in table.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@data-live='false']"):
```

As per your previous line :

```
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='foot-market']")
```

*table* is a *List* and you can't invoke `find_element_by_xpath()` on a *List*. `find_element_by_xpath()` can be invoked either on *webdriver* instance or on a *webelement*.

Your working code will be as follows :

```
all_tds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='foot-market']//td[@class='today-name']")
for tds in all_tds :
    tds.click()
    #try for one row first and break out
    break
```

> Note : This is a basic solution to overcome your error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'` and to `try for one row first`

---

### Update

If you intend to loop through all the `td` elements of the table, then you have to capture the *base url* so we can revert back to the main page to *find* and *click* the subsequent elements as follows :

```
base_url = driver.current_url
count_all_tds = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='foot-market']//td[@class='today-name']"))
for td in range(count_all_tds):
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='foot-market']//td[@class='today-name']")[td].click()
    # code block for other required actions and finally redirect to base_url
    driver.get(base_url)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. thats True from the error i got ...  but how can i find the elements in the list then?

Comment: All the _tds_ are already in the list now. Iterate over them one by one. _#try for one row first_ and let me know the status.

Comment: It works.... wow .... but issue is that it works only for the first click. even after adding driver.back() doesn't loop all clicks().   How can i fix that?

Comment: on refreshing an error arises since the td and table will go stale

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <td class="today-name"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: yeah. ill work on that. Thank you for the answer though. i appreciate