# Python selenium 'list' object has no attribute 'text' error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to copy text from comment on a website`<span class="auto-link">yes</span>`    and my python code is

```
element=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="auto-link"][1]')
print(element.text)
```

but I keep on getting the 'list' object has no attribute 'text' error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: yes it works! thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' - Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223011/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-click-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['list' object has no attribute 'get\_attribute' while iterating through WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735375/list-object-has-no-attribute-get-attribute-while-iterating-through-webelemen)

Answer (score 12):

I'm using selenium in python. Try this code I hope this will work for you.

```
    element=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="auto-link"][1]')

    for value in element:
        print(value.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've never used Selenium, but based on the error and your response, the answer is pretty clear.

When you search for a class, there may be multiple matching elements, so it returns a list of all found matches. Even if you only have a single element with that class, it will still return a list for consistency.

Just grab the first element from the found elements:

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="auto-link"][1]')
# ^ Renamed to reflect type better

print(elements[0].text)
#              ^ Grab the first element
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work when you are looking for more than one element and takes the first element that matches the xpath:

```
element=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="auto-link"][1]').get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(element)
```

This is when you are looking only for one:

```
element=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="auto-link"]').get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(element)
```

The output:

```
>>>yes
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# instead of driver.find_elements_by_xpath() use driver.find_element_by_xpath() to get the individual element of the table
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Google Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://testautomationpractice.blogspot.com/") 

# Get Number of Rows
rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='HTML1']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr"))

# Get Number of Columns
columns = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='HTML1']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th"))

print("Number of Rows:", rows)
print("Number of Columns:", columns)

# In web table index starts with 1 instead of 0 
for row in range(2, rows+1):
    for col in range(1,columns+1):
        value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='HTML1']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr["+str(row)+"]/td["+str(col)+"]").text
        print(value, end='      ')
    print()


time.sleep(5)

# Close the Browser
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

First Write the xpath of span in which you are currently working and then add the index number in the last of xpath but within it like given below.

```
from selenium import webdriver`
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.example.org")
element=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="auto-link"[1]').click()
print(element)
```

[1] is the index number of my value which i want to access.

Answer (score 1):

dont use `find_elements_by_xpath`, but `find_element_by_xpath`

Answer (score 0):

There are 10 elements by this selector, it prints all of them

```py
roles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//label[@class='container-checkmark disabled'])")

for x in range(len(roles)):
    print(roles[x].text)
```