# Print everything in div tag selenium python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a website which has some info under its div tag like this

```
<div> id="searchResults" class="multiple-view-elements"
<span>name</name>
<span>info</name>
<span>info</name>

<span>name</name>
......
```

My code

```
print ('-------------------------------------------------------------')
resp=driver.find_elements_by_id('searchResults').text
print (resp)
driver.quit()
```

it gives me this error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49900117/4513879 myabe its help you

Comment: Thanks for replying, I already tried that didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `find_elements`. which returns list of element and 'list' object don't have attribute/method 'text'

Use `find_element` e.g. `resp=driver.find_element_by_id('searchResults').text` to get the single element

Comment: thanks man it worked also is there any way to find lement by class name

Comment: Yup. you can browse some good tutorial over the internet. https://www.techbeamers.com/locate-elements-selenium-python/#locate-element-by-class-name

Answer (score 0):

You try to get the text attribute from the div elements, but there is no text contains  for the element.

for example

```html
<h3 class="LC20lb">Hi | Definition of Hi by Merriam-Webster</h3>
```

here the header h3 contains **Hi | Definition of Hi by Merriam-Webster**

so if you perform get text Method here you will get "Hi | Definition of Hi by Merriam-Webster",but your web element div has not text for contains attribute so get text is failed there.

so just clear your question what you wants to pint.

If any web element have text attribute or any contains text is there then you can try

```js
String value= driver.findElement(By.id("")).getText();
```